# Extended Session in L5 does not persist between requests

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

I am extending the session provider in order to persist some required data. I started editing `AppServiceProvider's boot method`:

```
\Session::extend('desk', function($app)
{
    return new Desk();
});
```

`Desk` class looks like:

```
namespace App\Services;


use Illuminate\Session\ExistenceAwareInterface;

class Desk implements \SessionHandlerInterface, ExistenceAwareInterface{

    /**
     * The existence state of the session.

     * @var bool
     */
    protected $exists;

    public function close()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function destroy($session_id)
    {
        $session = $em->find('Session', $session_id);
        $em->remove($session);
        $em->flush();

        return true;
    }

    public function gc($maxlifetime)
    {
        // TODO: Implement gc() method.
    }

    public function open($save_path, $session_id)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function read($session_id)
    {
        $session = $em->find('Session', $session_id);

        if ($sesion !== null){
            $this->exists = true;
            return  $session->getPayload();
        }
    }

    public function write($session_id, $session_data)
    {
        $session = $em->find('Session', $session_id);

        if ($session === null){
            $session = new Session($session_id, $session_data);
            $em->persist($session);
        }
        else{
            $session->setPayload($session_data);
        }

        $em->flush();

        $this->exists = true;
    }


    public function setExists($value)
    {
        $this->exists = $value;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

After finish the implementation, I changed the session config to this:

```
return [
    'driver' => 'desk',
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path().'/framework/sessions',
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'lote_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
];
```

When I load the page there is not problem, but after do a success login request and then, refresh the page, the session expires and the user is a guest again. Do I miss something?

Additional information: if I revert the session driver to "file", everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for others that need/want to extends the session provider like me, pay attention to session's table structure. My mistake was that the `payload` column was set as:

```
payload varchar(255) not null
```

Because of laravel serialization data, the payload value could be has more than  255 characters length, in consequence, it will break the data and make it inconsistent. You can consider:

```
payload text not null
```